# 101 Qt stylesheet margins padding hack guide in C++. Setting padding doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtstylesheets

After months of research and asking here, I found out the solution to make margins be reset to 0 and paddings to 0, stylize a widget and start from scratch a design using stylesheets in qt.
The widgets must be **containers** of something else.

**101 Guide to style widgets margins/padding using stylesheets in qt4**

- Create any kind of BoxModel stylable widget (not `QWidget`, use `QFrame` instead!). [Check documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/stylesheet-reference.html)
- Assign a normal layout to it.
- If you don't want the default margins, which are big as apox. 8px more or less, you have to set the layout (not the widget, you can, but doesn't work) contents margin to 0: `setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)`.
- Optionally (I don't know which cases), to bring everything to the extreme reset (no borders, nothing at all), set spacing to 0 too. `setSpacing(0)`
- set the widget object name to a custom name: `setObjectName("name")`.
- set your style changing QFrame by your widget: `QFrame#name  { things... }`

If you want to stylize the custom widget and you have a **custom class name** for it, and you intend to use the NAME of the class instead of using `setObjectName`, add this small hack reimplementing your paint method, which is included in Qt Stylesheet documentation example.

> If you subclass from QWidget, you need to provide a paintEvent for
>   your custom QWidget as below:
>
> ```
> void CustomWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
>  {
>     QStyleOption opt;
>     opt.init(this);
>     QPainter p(this);
>     style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
> }
> ```
>
> The above code is a no-operation if there is no stylesheet set.
>
> Warning: Make sure you **define the Q_OBJECT macro** for your custom
>   widget.

Then you can create the style by using the class name. `ClassName {}`

---

Now, I have a serious problem which I shared with other people and I had no solution. **Padding doesn't work at all. Only margins work.**

So

```
ClassName
{ padding: 200px; margin: 5px; }
```

does the same as

```
ClassName
{ margin: 5px; }
```

That brings the bothering situation when you have to **create subcontainers with margins** to add a padding. That brings us to an infinite hierarchy... Which is not desirable at all.

Does anybody know how to completely finish my 101 guide?

Comment: This `ClassName` class of yours. Is it a subclass of `QFrame`?

Comment: Nope. It is a QFrame#name

Comment: Something wrong there? could be the answer?

Comment: The doc says this about padding: This property is supported by `QAbstractItemView` subclasses, `QAbstractSpinBox` subclasses, `QCheckBox`, `QComboBox`, `QFrame`, `QGroupBox`, `QLabel`, `QLineEdit`, QMenu, `QMenuBar`, `QPushButton`, `QRadioButton`, `QSplitter`, `QTextEdit`, and `QToolTip`. So I don't think you can use it for a custom `QWidget` subclass.

Comment: I knew it but didn't realize that my widget was a QWidget subclass, not QFrame, which is what i said in the post. :-D  I found it 10 min ago!. But thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Padding works**

My problem comes from the class I used for checking that padding didn't work. It was a subclass of QWidget, which, as documentation clearly says:

> Supports only the background, background-clip and background-origin
> properties.

So my background property was working and I didn't understand why padding didn't.

So I answered my own question without knowing it.

Comment: Somehow you screwed up the Q&A model. This is pretty confusing. Remove the edits, state a clear question, put the answer in the answer post. For the sake of readability.